# Gmail not sending with env variables in Rails 4 project, but env variables are displayed in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmail, environment-variables, development-environment

I am working on a tutorial about ActiveRecords and needed to configure ActionMailer.

I have Environmental Variables configured in ~/.bashrc and this system has been working reliably.

I configured everything in the development.rb

```
development.rb

config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true

config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "localhost:3000" }

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              "smtp.gmail.com",
    port:                 587,
    domain:               "gmail.com",
    user_name:            ENV[ "GMAIL_USERNAME" ],
    password:             ENV[ "GMAIL_PASSWORD"],
    authentication:       "plain",
    enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

My contact_form.rb model is:

```
class ContactForm < MailForm::Base

    attribute :name, :validate => true

    attribute :email, :validate => /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i

    attribute :message, :validate => true

    # Declare the e-mail headers
    def headers
        {
            :subject => 'ArcadeNomad - Contact Request',
            :to => ENV[ "OWNER_EMAIL" ],
            :from => ENV[ "OWNER_EMAIL" ]
        }
    end

end
```

When I test everything in rails console i get:

```
Machine:dev_arcadenomad_com Account$ rails c --sandbox
Loading development environment in sandbox (Rails 4.2.1)
Any modifications you make will be rolled back on exit
>> contact = ContactForm.new(:name => 'Name', :email => 'SomeMail@domain.tld', :message => 'I love ArcadeNomad!')
=> #<ContactForm:0x007fde0d6d38a8 @name="Name", @email="SomeMail@domain.tld", @message="I love ArcadeNomad!">
>> contact.valid?
=> true
>> contact.deliver    
  Rendered /Users/MyAccount/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@learn-active-records/gems/mail_form-1.5.1/lib/mail_form/views/mail_form/contact.erb (8.1ms)

MailForm::Notifier#contact: processed outbound mail in 239.6ms

Sent mail to mymail@gmail.com (6.9ms)
Date: Sat, 27 Jun 2015 17:32:01 +0200
From: mymail@gmail.com
To: mymail@gmail.com
Message-ID: <LongString@machine.domain.tl.mail>
Subject: ArcadeNomad - Contact Request
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<h4 style="text-decoration:underline">ArcadeNomad - Contact Request</h4>


  <p><b>Name:</b>
  Name</p>

  <p><b>Email:</b>
  SomeMail@domain.tld</p>

  <p><b>Message:</b>
  I love ArcadeNomad!</p>


=> true
```

But no mail is delivered.

If I hardcode my credentials into development.rb everything works.
When I test for ENV[ "GMAIL_USERNAME" ] in rails console my mail credentials are displayed correctly.

What am I missing?

Comment: Your CAPS LOCK appears to be BROKEN.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand. Do you mean, because I highlighted some words with capital letters?

Comment: Yes. It makes your post more difficult to read, not easier.

Comment: As for your question, I'm not a Ruby expert, but I don't see anywhere where you actually try to send the message.

Comment: Sorry, I will keep in mind not to use caps lock so much. I added some info about my problem.

Comment: What is dev.arcadenomad.com? Is that a testing server run by somebody else? Mail capabilities may be disabled. Also, if you are really using a gmail.com From address, that may be part of the problem. Gmail will not accept email from a gmail.com address that isn't sent through one of their servers.

Comment: I am doing the "EasyActive Records for Rails Tutorial" by Jason Gilmore. dev.arcadenomad.com is just a local testing server. The point is: if I hardcode my mail credentials in development.rb environment it works, but if I put my environmental variables from my .bashrc it does not work.