# Rails 5.2 not loading environment variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables

I have defined Gmail username and password to use in ActionMailer config for sending out emails and use them in the config in this way:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              "smtp.gmail.com",
    port:                 587,
    domain:               "example.com",
    authentication:       :plain,
    user_name:            ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
    password:             ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"],
    enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

With this setup emails are not delivered, however if I manually type the username and password as strings it works.
I have cnonfimed the variables are properly defined in rails console:

```
rails c
ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"] #=> "my_username"
```

I have logged out and logged back in to the system and restarted the terminal to source my .bash_profile
`echo $GMAIL_USERNAME` returns proper value.
In `todos#index` action I `puts ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"]` and it also returns proper username. Why does it not work then? Any ideas?

Comment: How did you get to know that the problem is with the environment variables?

Comment: As I said, after I've set username and password as the actual username and password manually it worked fine but now I've tried again and it does not work. I could swear it worked yesterday :(

Comment: So what is the issue?

Comment: I don't know. Found one more similar question unanswered on SO. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31090589/gmail-not-sending-with-env-variables-in-rails-4-project-but-env-variables-are-d

You can try something different like `"#{ENV['GMAIL_USERNAME']}"` and see if it works. Although it does seem non-sense to do it. Otherwise, it's hard to tell the error without digging the system which throws the error

Comment: How are they being set, are you using `dot-env` gem or something?

Comment: I generally user [Figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro)

Comment: export GMAIL_USERNAME="..." in .zshrc (I am using zsh) @RockwellRice

Comment: The `tap` method might be useful here as you could do something like `.tap{|a| puts "="*50 + "'#{a}'" }` on the result of ENV["gmail/password"] and see what they're being set to.

Comment: How are you starting your application?

Comment: I've just setup my Rails app with Sendgrid and it works so this must be some Gmail issue. It used to work in the past for me so maybe they changed something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just setup my Rails app with Sendgrid and it works so this must be some Gmail issue. It used to work in the past for me so maybe they changed something.

Comment: Might be a setting you have to switch on in GMail to use SMTP. There's one for IMAP.

Answer (score 0):

so, you run this on a server? do you have apache or nginx in front of it? putting `GMAIL_USERNAME` into your user's `.bashrc` won't help because whatever server you run the rails app through won't read the `.bashrc`